# Symfony2 Twig Style Sheet

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am following a tutorial for symphony 2 but cant get the style sheet to load all I get is a 404.

I have tried also adding it into the route but I get a permission error on the style sheet.

**app/Resources/views/base.html.twig**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}symblog{% endblock %} - symblog</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}

            <link href="{{ asset('css/screen.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        {% endblock %}
```

I have added the style sheet into app/Resources/views/web/css/screen.css

Any ideas why this is not working? [Tutorial](http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/configuration-and-templating.html)

Comment: Did you check css file permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put css files in a wrong directory.

It should be **web/css/screen.css** instead of **app/Resources/views/web/css/screen.css**

I also suggest you to use assetic instead of manually put css and js to the web directory. These articles might help (take a look at the *assets:install* command):

- [**How to Use Assetic for Asset Management**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html)
- [**Linking to Assets**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#linking-to-assets)
- [**Including Stylesheets and JavaScripts in Twig**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#including-stylesheets-and-javascripts-in-twig)

Answer (score 1):

Projects assets (resources from your **app/** folder) are ignored by **assets:install** command. Only resources from bundles will be copied into the **web/** folder automatically.

You should place your app (project) resources directly in the web/ folder.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html

By the way: ONLY the web/ folder is public. 
Look at the rendered source code of your html in the browser and you will see that your css file is prefixed with a **web/**. This is what the **asset()** command does